# Make chapters start on odd pages

Tags: chapters, blank-page

I need to make my chapters start on odd pages and keep heading and page numbering for the blank page before it. I read somewhere that Latex makes this in book documents by default, but I'm still having chapters on even pages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage[figureposition=bottom]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\hyphenation{hoch-warm-fester Legier-ungs-bestandteile simul-ieren makrosko-pischen SX-Nickellegierung-en Legierungs-bestand-teile SX-Superlegier-ung Multiphasen-feld-Methode Fehlpassu-ng Mikrostruktur-entwicklung}
\raggedbottom
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\ \fi\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
\markboth{#1}{}}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mcTwo}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\linespread{1.8}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document} 
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE (minimum working example) that shows your basic document setup and an instance of problem behavior, I.e., of a chapter that starts on an even-numbered page. Without such information it's going to be nearly impossible to give suggestions on how to fix the problem, or problems, you're encountering.

Comment: @Mico I added my code to the question. Thank you.

Comment: Your code (MWE) seems to be incomplete.

Comment: @Fran : This duplicate seems to address the exact opposite problem. This question is likely to be too-localized, since what the OP is asking for is the default behavior.

Comment: Exactly, it says if I need the default behaviour I have to remove openany, but I already didn't use `openany´.

Comment: Thanks for posting some extra code. Unfortunately, it doesn't generate the problem behavior you're looking to fix. In addition, it contains a lot of stuff that's clearly unrelated to the issue at hand.